# How to force camera2 preview to be a video (for testing purposes)?

Tags: android, android-camera2

My intent is to have a video I've recorded to be seen by the camera2 api as the PREVIEW so that I don't have to test it manually every time in my device and so I can have a standardized way of testing the code.

The idea came from the image you get in adb emulator when you have a camera preview session being displayed in a textureview, as seen below.

[image]

I want to do the same but with a video that is suited to test my use-case.

I haven't found a way of doing this yet, can anyone help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just curious if you ever got a working solution on this. I have been researching about this but so far no luck.